# Does this math formula with $1/PI\begin{cases}^\infty_{-\infty}\end{cases}$ mean anything?

Tags: notation

I happened upon an image on the Internet

[image: weird math 1]
<sub>(source: [news.com.au](http://resources3.news.com.au/images/2012/09/18/1226476/682687-teachers-thinkstock.jpg))</sub>

and I wondered whether the math on the chalkboard means anything. Using Google's image search, I found three other related images.

[image: weird math 2]

[image: weird math 3]

[image: weird math 4]
<sub>(source: [nees.org](https://nees.org/site/images/stories/academy/teachers.jpg))</sub>

Piecing together the math from the various angles shows some mismatched grouping symbols.

My question: Ignoring the possible typos, does the "math" mean anything? Or is this an example of stock photography trying to appear mathy?

Comment: It's almost an integral, but written weirdly.

Comment: Looks like someone copied something they didn't understand. If instead of the curly bracket $\{$ they had written an integral sign $\int$, then they appear to be something like the formulae for Fourier series/transform.

Comment: You'd have to ask the guy pointing very proudly at $$1/PI\big\{_{-\infty}^\infty\ f(t) \sin ty\ dt,$$ I think he just discovered its meaning.

Comment: So the best suggestion is to replace $\{$ with $\int$ and $PI$ with $\pi$.

Comment: I remember I have seen an OCR software which have mistaken the integral sign $\int$ as the parenthesis when extracting math from old book. So the { part doesn't look too strange to me. In fact, the $acy |$ on the second line also looks like an OCR mistake to me (the original should be $a(y)$).

Comment: The most amazing thing here is that the answer saying "No it does not mean anything" has +18... Seems reasonable!

Comment: Honestly, that the stock photographer setting up the shoot didn't have the wherewithal to change PI to $\pi$ is the most amusing part. One gets the impression that the photographer has had one or two demanding clients in their day.

Comment: @achillehui Nice call on the OCR idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Googling `fourier "a(y)" "b(y)"` yields [this first hit](http://www.math.com/tables/advanced/fourier.htm):

[image: Fourier Integral of the function f(x)]

Comment: +1 It looks like this is the original text for what's on the board. What the board is showing is the output of the text under OCR.

Comment: while I am happy to have gotten 180 points for essentially nothing, this is the right answer and should be accepted!

Comment: Very nice find via Google!

Comment: Thanks @hunter ! Your endorsement has boosted my rep past the 2k threshold

Answer (score 17):

It's safe to say that the math doesn't mean anything. No branch of mathematics or science or anything else uses the symbol $\{$ for an integral sign, and there are mismatched parentheses.